# GIMP Script-FU - Error: not enough arguments

Tags: arguments, gimp, script-fu

GIMP script-fu-newbie here.

I can't see anywhere in the documentation of GIMP 2.6 why this shouldn't work:

```
;Define the main function
(define (script-fu-rubber-stamp img drawable)
      (gimp-image-undo-group-start img)
      (plug-in-randomize-pick 1 img drawable 90 7 FALSE 10)
      (plug-in-oilify 1 img drawable 5 0)
      (gimp-image-undo-group-end img)
)

;Register the script w/ GIMP.
(script-fu-register
      "script-fu-rubber-stamp"            ;func name
      "Rubber Stamp"                      ;menu label
      "Image to rubberstamp"              ;description
      "Me"                                ;author
      "Copyright 2011, Me"                ;copyright notice
      "Nov. 2011"                         ;date created
      ""                                  ;image type that the script works on
)

(script-fu-menu-register "script-fu-rubber-stamp" "<Image>/Script-Fu")
```

It shows up in GIMP, but when I run it, it says:

```
Error: not enough arguments
```

But if I look in the Script-FU Console, it seems the be right... unless the error of my ways is not in the functioncalls...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ARGH naturally... script-fu-register needs to say what img and drawable is:

```
(script-fu-register
  "script-fu-rubber-stamp"            ;func name
  "Rubber Stamp"                      ;menu label
  "Image to rubberstamp"              ;description
  "Me"                                ;author
  "Copyright 2011, Me"                ;copyright notice
  "Nov. 2011"                         ;date created
  ""                                  ;image type that the script works on
  SF-IMAGE "Input Image" 0
  SF-DRAWABLE "Input Drawable" 0
)
```